# Old school tables over divs

Tags: html, css, html-table, w3c

I am an old school web designer and still tend to opt for tables over divs. I find it easier to do public websites that way especially with the amount of current browser platforms we have around.

I can do divs perfectly fine but find tables easier when working in cross browsers

If I am doing professional websites would I be regarded as doing it wrong, being unprofessional or frowned upon? Would it be classed as non-standard or old fashioned?

Comment: Yes to all 5 questions. The alternative to tables is not divs though, it is the most semantically appropriate elements with CSS.

Comment: Typically you don't just use divs on everything, but the actual element that's applicable: is it a `header`, a `section`, an `h1`, a `p`, a `table`, a `figure` or whatever. Just swapping divs for tables doesn't help.

Comment: clearly i need to update my skills. I've never used header,section, h1 or figure..

Comment: Even in HTML4, the spec was pretty clear about not using tables for layout:  "Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content as this may present problems when rendering to non-visual media" http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

Answer (score 5):

You are using semantic tables to achieve a grid like layout. The reason why this is wrong (and frowned upon) is mainly because the layout information is in the wrong place. Html should be used for semantics (content without look) and the styling should be done in css (look without content). So only if the *information* is tabular should you use the table tag.

However, the question is a good one because the really nice alternatives are still around the corner (see upcoming CSS layout engines below).

#### How do you now if you should use a semantical table?

1. Each row should represent some topic of the same nature as other rows or topics
   related to the peer topics.
2. Each column for each row should be related to a certain aspect of the topic.
3. The decision on placing some information in a cell should reasonably be based
   on 1) and 2) and not on aesthetics.

## The modern CSS alternative

The W3C has several upcoming solutions. The one closest matching your need is currently being implemented in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-grid-layout). This CSS is what you are looking for. It will be available in all smoking hot new browsers this winter. So for the next few years, you should use older (and more cumbersome) CSS (see below).

[image: CSS Grid layout]

An other is the CSS Flexbox (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox).

These specs are to new for general use though, but it is the way these kind of layouts will be conducted right.

## The current CSS alternative to grid like layouts

I would use a CSS grid to avoid tables today. You can use this code as a starting point.

http://simplegrid.info

Using CSS that works on all browsers as in the example above is a little more work, but this works on all browsers today.

Answer (score 1):

Tables *should only be used to display tabular data* period. Any other use of them is un-semantic, wrong and old-school. The only place tables are acceptable for layout is HTML email...

The rule is to use the most semantic element for the situation, which is what Quentin is alluding to, so definitely don't do:

```
<table class="header">
```

And try and avoid:

```
<div class="header">
```

Opting instead (where possible) for:

```
<header>
```

Comment: <header> instead of <div class="header">.You've confused me here

Comment: @Lee: Welcome to web design in 2012 :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend, but the current HTML 5 Draft specification allow the use of table for layout.

How to differentiate a layout table vs a data table

> **Probably a layout table**
>
> - The use of the role attribute with the value presentation
> - The use of the border attribute with the non-conforming value 0
> - The use of the non-conforming cellspacing and cellpadding attributes with the value 0
>
> **Probably a non-layout table**
>
> - The use of caption, thead, or th elements
> - The use of the headers and scope attributes
> - The use of the border attribute with a value other than 0
> - Explicit visible borders set using CSS
>
> **Not a good indicator**
>
> *(both layout and non-layout tables have historically been given this attribute)*
>
> - The use of the summary attribute

reference: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-table-element.html#the-table-element

In regards of doing cross browsers website that should be easy to reach even if you use tables or div to layout the webpage.

But what is about to make them accessible by targeting a **WCAG 2.0 Level AA conformance**. [The WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/) have a full set of [Techniques for HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/) that can be used as best HTML Coding Pratices and to create accessible website.

[Quick reference to the guideline and techniques: How to Meet WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/)

:-)

Comment: "the current HTML 5 Draft specification allow the use of table for layout" You've misinterpreted it. Every spec has allowed the use of tables for layout since there really is no **technical** restriction that disallows the use of tables for layout, but no spec has ever encouraged tables for layout.

Comment: The HTML5 draft has a mention to it and there still exist web site that use table for layout. From an accessibility point of view, that is not an issue when the appropriate ARIA role is use on the table element and the content is ordered in a meaningful sequence. :-)